# Why would changing a method, but not its mock, result in a change to test behaviour?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I was recently reviewing some code written by a contract developer who's now left the business when I spotted an unusual change to this unit test (it's incomplete - only posting relevant code).

```
// Arrange
byte[] returnData = new byte[] { 2, 23, 56 };
this.mockCsvMemoryWriter.Setup(writer => writer.WriteCsvToMemory(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<AssetDetailsCsvModel>>())).Returns(returnData);

// Act
var actual = await this.target.GetAssetsDownload(null, null, ListViewModel.AssetStatus.Undefined);

// Assert
actual.ShouldSatisfyAllConditions(
    () => actual.ShouldBeAssignableTo<FileStreamResult>().ContentType.ShouldBe("text/csv"),
    () => actual.ShouldBeAssignableTo<FileStreamResult>().FileStream.ShouldNotBeNull(),
    () => actual.ShouldBeAssignableTo<FileStreamResult>().FileStream.Length.ShouldBeGreaterThan(0));
```

The change was on the last line, which had been altered to `ShouldBeGreaterThanOrEqualTo(0)`.

What's odd about this is that the target of the test, the `GetAssetsDownload` method has not changed. One of its underlying dependencies has, but it's mocked out - the `writer.WriteCsvToMemory` method.

Given that this is mocked, I would not expect its behaviour to change. But it does. Prior to the change, the `returnData` bytes  are returned as expected. With the change, an empty byte array is returned instead.

Using debug and breakpoints, I have verified that in both cases the `GetAssetsDownload` method  is using the mock and that the actual `writer.WriteCsvToMemory` method is not called.

Why would changing a method that's mocked out, without changing the mock, result in a change to the test behaviour?

Comment: Well if the mock (WriteCsvToMemory) hasn't changed, and GetAssetsDownload hasn't changed, then maybe a different underlying dependency has changed? You'll just have to do some more debugging to work out where the difference is.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer Apologies if I'm being obtuse but if the mock is the same, and the assertion against the mock is the same, surely it has nothing to do with any dependency? The return from the method invokes the mock and the assert checks what's in the mock.

Comment: What is the change that causes this change in test behavior? Also you might want to include a more complete test class. Specifically, it may be helpful to see how `this.mockCsvMemoryWriter` and `this.target` are initialized and used elsewhere in the class.

Comment: @MattThrower. The assert does not check the mock. The assert checks the result of GetAssetsDownload, which may or may not call the mock since we can't see the code. If the mock hasn't changed then it must be something else that has changed.

Comment: the code you posted is not enough for us to judge. You could simply revert the change to see what happens. Does the test behave the same as before? If yes then dump the change. Also, the fact that it was written by a contractor is irrelevant

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu Thanks. I eventually found the problem but it's too niche to be worth posting as an answer - essentially down the chain an overload signature had been altered in such a way that the code was no longer sure which overload to run, hence the mock wasn't being touched at all. I should probably delete the question